# Solr Delete By limiting number of documents

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, http-delete

We are trying to do date based delete of Solr documents using following command.
Is it possible to restrict the no. of documents to say 200K?

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/keyspace.core/update?commit=true --data '<delete><query>timestamp:[* TO NOW/DAY-30DAYS]</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

Comment: This question is not very clear. If you want to do timestamp-based delete query, where does the limit come in? Are you saying you just want the latest 200K documents?

Comment: The reason for limiting the documents is because we don't overload the cluster by performing huge deletes. So, if we need to delete 1M documents then we can batch it by deleting 200K documents at a time so that the cluster does not gets overloaded. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to add a limit while deleting data from `solr`.

You can delete the data from `Solr` either by `Id` or by `Query`.

Delete the documents by Id

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=
<delete><query>id:298253</query></delete>&commit=true
```

If you want to delete items that matches more than one field, just add another query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=
<delete><query>id:298253</query>
<query>entitytype:BlogEntry</query></delete>&commit=true
```

If you want to delete all items in the index..

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with dropping old documents from a large collection efficiently is to not have a monolithic collection in a first place. This is often seen with collections that store constantly accumulating logs.

The solution is to use [collection aliases](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-CreateormodifyanAliasforaCollection) and to have each individual collection represent a particular time period with the 'alias' aggregating relevant collections into a combined view. Then, an older collection can be dropped completely by just reissuing a new alias command with different collection list.